# What is the reason for adding noindex to a contact us page?

Tags: html, seo, meta, html5boilerplate, noindex

I am reading the html5-boilerplate [extend.md](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/doc/extend.md#hide-pages-from-search-engines) doc and it states:

> According to Heather Champ, former community manager at Flickr, you should not allow search engines to index your "Contact Us" or "Complaints" page if you value your sanity.

What is the reason for adding `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` to a contact us page? I am wondering if the underlying reason may help to identify other pages that should probably not be indexed. I can understand the preference to not have a complaints page indexed, since there may be some very critical discussion on those pages. But I thought it was interesting that contact us page should also not be indexed.

Unfortunately, searching for this topic is hard, since the search results seem to always show the same quote above unaccompanied by the underlying reason - so I am hoping someone can help me out here! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a matter of opinion. I see value in having contact us pages indexed, and complaints handling/procedure pages indexed too. Why not ? These pages are part of transparency for end users.